# convert row values into columns based on duplicate ID in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a large mysql table called 'ride' with columns as shown below:

```
+---------+------------+
| ride_ID | person_ID | 
+---------+------------+
| ride_1   | person1   |
| ride_1   | person2   | 
| ride_1   | person3   | 
| ride_2   | person1   | 
| ride_2   | person4   | 
| ride_3   | person1   | 
| ride_3   | person5   | 
| ride_3   | person2   | 
| ride_3   | person3   | 
+---------+------------+
```

All I want to apply groupby on column `ride_ID` such that all the `person_ID` should be in multiple columns with respective column names.

Expected output as,

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ride_ID | person_ID1| person_ID2  | person_ID3  | person_ID4  | person_ID5  |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ride_1  | person1   | person2     | person3     |             |             |
| ride_2  | person1   |             |             | person4     |             |
| ride_3  | person1   | person2     | person3     |             |  person5    | 
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This is PIVOT, and it is not implemented in MySQL. You may emulate it (use searching - there exists some solutions) or perform this pivotting on the lient side using its reporting subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the row number per person in order to set 1 for person 1, 2 for person 2 etc.
Then you can use an aggregate function and group by ride_id. Something like this:

```
SELECT
ride_id,  
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 THEN person_id END) AS person_ID1,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 2 THEN person_id END) AS person_ID2,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 3 THEN person_id END) AS person_ID3,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 4 THEN person_id END) AS person_ID4,
MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 5 THEN person_id END) AS person_ID5
FROM (SELECT r.ride_id, r.person_id, sub.RowNr
FROM ride r JOIN (SELECT person_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as RowNr
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM 
ride) x) sub ON r.person_id = sub.person_id) y
GROUP BY ride_id;
```

This will produce the correct result for your sample data.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1rm-clR)

But I recommend to avoid such things in SQL queries. It would be better to do this in your application. Pivot is not SQL's strength, especially not MySQL's.